# Building a Binary matrix out of a data frame after converting values of one column into rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, binary

I want to build a binary matrix from a data frame that looks like the following; two columns one has the cell type and the other contains markers.

```
Markers                                   Cell type                     
"CD3D, CD3E, CD3G, CD4"                   Peripheral blood_Normal_T helper cell
"CD3D, CD3E, CD3G, PTPRC"                 Peripheral blood_Normal_Memory T cell
"IL2RA, CD3D, CD3E, CD3G, CD4, FOXP3"     Peripheral blood_Normal_Regulatory T (Treg) cell
"CD3D, CD3E, CD3G, CD4, IFNG"             Peripheral blood_Normal_T helper1 (Th1) cell
"CD3D, CD3E, CD3G, CD4, IL4"              Peripheral blood_Normal_T helper2 (Th2) cell
"CD3D, CD3E, CD3G, CD4, IL17RA"           Peripheral blood_Normal_T helper17 (Th17) cell
"PROM1, PECAM1, CD34, PTPRC"              Peripheral blood_Gastric Cancer_Endothelial progenitor cell
"PROM1, PECAM1, CD34, PTPRC"              Peripheral blood_Gastric Cancer_Endothelial cell
CD14                                      Blood_Normal_Monocyte
NRP1                                      Blood_Normal_Plasmacytoid dendritic cell
GP1BA                                     Blood_Normal_T helper cell
```

I would like the final output to take the following structure. so each cell type is a column on its own and each marker which some times comes single value and some other times they are several markers separated by a comma as rows. Finally, the matrix values for each cell type indicate 1 if the marker existed in the markers columns for this specific cell type or  0 if not.

```
         Blood_Normal_T helper cell         Peripheral blood_Gastric Cancer_Endothelial progenitor cell
PROM1                 0                                              1
PECAM1                0                                              1
CD34                  0                                              1
PTPRC                 0                                              1
GP1BA                 1                                              0
.....
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(Markers) %>%
   xtabs(~., .)
```

If you are just using base R:

```
ind <- seq(nrow(df))

table(merge(cbind(ind = ind, df[-1]),
            stack(setNames(strsplit(df$Markers, ","), ind)))[3:2])
```